# tinymce formating not working on live

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, tinymce

Using tinymce for content, it works fine on local server but break formatting on remote server.

saving content:

```
mysql_real_escape_string( htmlentities($slide_name,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'))
```

when retrieve:

```
html_entity_decode($slide_name, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')
```

on local server it display content correctly:

```
<p><strong style="text-decoration: underline;">Contact:</strong> 0000-<span style="color: #ff0000;">245</span></p>
```

on remote (after 1st update):

```
<p><span style="\"><strong style="\">Contact:</strong></span> 0000-<span style="\">245</span></p>
```

use `utf8_general_ci` collation for both databases (remote/local)

Comment: what about the client, can you be a bit more clear?

Comment: You may have diff between 2 ini files. Try php info on each machine & look for diff. Particularity check magic quotes

Comment: thanks yeah there is difference, magic_quotes ON for remote and OFF for local. `remote: magic_quotes_gpc On On` and `local: magic_quotes_gpc Off Off` so what you suggest now? both running `php 5.3.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of searching and **Toby Allen** hint I found a solution.
Here was a problem:
`magic_quotes_gpc` were `ON` on remote server and `magic_quotes_gpc` were `OFF` on Local server.

As we can't control remote server up to php configuration level so we need to OFF magic_quotes_gpc run time.

Found a code snip from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
?>
```

if possible OFF magic_quotes_gpc using php.ini otherwise we can use function like above to switch OFF magic_quotes_gpc runtime.

I am posting this answer for future searchers.